Prove that $R_{>0}$ is not a vector space with addition and multiplication defined in the usual way.
My solution: $0 \notin \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
Am I missing something? This question was a homework problem but the answer seems way too simple compared to the other questions.

How do you deduce that $\Bbb R_>$ is not a vector space from the fact that $0\notin\Bbb R_>$?

perhaps there some positive real number satisfying the properties of the identity under addition for $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$

@creillyucla but by definition of $\mathbb{R_{>0}}$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$, $x > 0$. Meaning if you assumed there was some $e \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$ that was the identity element, then, because $e > 0$ as well, $e + x > x$

You are correct. If addition is defined in the usual way then you don't have an additive identity. You could also argue that it is not closed under scalar multiplication, if the the field is $\mathbb R$ and scalar multiplication is defined in the usual way.

Your solution might seem incorrect because the identity element in $(\Bbb R,+)$ being unique (equal to $0$), i.e. (for any $e\in\Bbb R$)
$$(\forall y\in\Bbb R\quad y+e=y)\implies e=0$$
does not lead to
$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R_{>0}\quad x+e=x)\implies e=0.$$
However, you could complete it by arguing that if $(\Bbb R_{>0},+)$ had an identity element $e$, then that $e$ should be equal to $0$ because
$$(\forall t\in\Bbb R)(1+t=1\implies t=0).$$

If you want to prove that there is no additive identity in $\Bbb R_{>0}$, you have to prove that
$$\exists(e\in\Bbb R_{>0})\forall(v\in\Bbb R_{>0})(v+e=v)$$
is false.
Thus, you need to prove that
$$\forall(e\in\Bbb R_{>0})\exists(v\in\Bbb R_{>0})(v+e\neq v),$$
which means that whatever choice
of $e\in\Bbb R_{>0}$ is made, we can always find a $v\in\Bbb R_{>0}$ such that $v+e\neq v$.
Proof: Let $e\in\Bbb R_{>0}$ be arbitrary. Choose $v=e$. Note that $v\in\Bbb R_{>0}$ and
$$v+e=e+e=2e.$$
Since $e\in\Bbb R_{>0}$, we have $2e\neq e$. Thus,
$$v+e\neq e.$$
Since $e=v$, we have $v+e\neq v$.
